# Can consummation validate a one-witness Kiddushin?

Tags: halacha, kiddushin-eirusin

Can consummation validate a one-witness Kiddushin?

Halacha states, something like: "When a man consecrates a woman in the presence of a single witness, the kiddushin is not binding."

But Halacha also says, something like, "If a man consecrates a woman through sexual relations (no matter how much such action is frowned upon) ... the kiddushin is binding."

My question: is the second statement a Halacha loophole against the first one; that is / or, if a-man-and-a-woman so unfortunately have only one witness, then should they go ahead and have sex (or consummate), in order to have a binding kiddushin?

Comment: If the consummation effects a binding kiddushin then isn't that validating a NO witness kiddushin and obviating the testimony of any 1 witness?

Comment: don't forget, for the consummation to be binding you need two witnesses to see them seclude themselves...

Comment: Why do you think consecration through relations is different than kiddushin with one witness? Consecration is just a translation of kiddushin, which you pointed out doesn't work without two witnesses.

Comment: Consummation needs two witnesses, or "public knowledge" (i.e. living together as a married couple) to be a valid kiddushin. So if we know they were together with the intention of being a married couple that would be a kiddushin even if it was not formally declared, but if only they know about it then it has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

There are three valid types of Kiddushin: money, using a document, and biah. (Kiddushin 1:1) All three need two witnesses to be effective.

Answer (score 0):

> Can consummation validate a one-witness Kiddushin?

If it is done in the correct way, i.e. he says to her in front of 2 kosher witnesses *התקדשי לי בביאה זו* and then immediately secludes himself with her. (As per Rashi on בכסף ובשטר in Kidushin 2b who says ביאה-  בא עליה ואמר התקדשי לי בביאה זו.‏)

But then he may as well give her the ring again (after she gives it back to him) and redo the Kidushin properly in front of 2 kosher witnesses.

> My (second) question: is the second statement a Halacha loophole against the first one; that is / or, if a-man-and-a-woman so, unfortunately, have only one witness, then should they go ahead and have sex (or consummate), in order to have a binding kiddushin?

Nope. Wouldn't help.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd call Kiddushei Biah "consummation" since after it is done they still need Nisuin to be fully married.

Comment: The first answer should be edited for clarity. If there are two witnesses, by definition it is not one witness.